# PInvoke error: trying to write or read to protected memory

Tags: c#, pinvoke, calling-convention

I know this question is asked alot, But I tried to switch calling conventions and it didn't work.
I am using a c++ dll in my c# winforms code.
My function works perfectly until the return statement, where it gives me this error. if someone can help me to understand why I will apreciate it alot.
this is the end of my c++ function:

```
ans += ";";
ans += rans;
cout << "returning value 2" << endl;
char* retval = new char[ans.size() + 1];
strcpy_s(retval,ans.size()+1, ans.c_str());
return retval;
```

ans is an std::string.

here is my c# code PInvoking and calling the function:

```
[DllImport("C:\\Users\\Boaz\\source\\repos\\Macro_Setter_DLL\\Debug\\Macro_Setter_DLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
static extern string Stop_Record();

string tmp = Stop_Record();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: The marshaler tries to deallocate the string by calling CoTaskMemFree. So you need to allocate with CoTaskMemAlloc. Possible other errors in the code we can't see. [mcve]

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The solution worked! Thanks you so much!!!!